# Accessing Call Log

Tags: android, edit, stock, calllog

Is there a way to access the `Dialer/Contacts/Call Log` of Android through an application?
I essentially want to add `features/information`, and I know that those databases are unable to be changed past queries and insertions, so I was wondering how to override the stock `Dialer/Contacts/Call Log`?  Preferably, I'd only like to change one of those, but any info will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query `android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI` for getting Callogs as:

```
String[] strFields = {
        android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, 
        android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE,
        android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME,
        android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_TYPE
        };
String strOrder = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC"; 

Cursor mCallCursor = getContentResolver().query(
        android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
        strFields,
        null,
        null,
        strOrder
        );
```

and in manifest.xml add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: But how would I go about override the built in CallLog, so that when the user clicks the standard CallLog button, it pulls my version up instead of theirs?  Sorry for confusion

Comment: no you can lunch dial activity as Intent intent25 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(
  Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER).setClassName("com.android.contacts",
     "com.android.contacts.DialtactsActivity").addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
     .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND).setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.contacts",
     "com.android.contacts.DialtactsActivity"));
  getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent25);